# When changing value to data pulled from firebase, the variable reverts to the initial value. How can I have the value stay?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a swift program in Xcode that pulls a list of events from a firebase database, makes a table view cell for each event, and puts the said cell in a table view. The problem lies that when I set the value of an array storing the events to whatever it pulls from the firebase, the value immediately reverts after I close the snapshot. Here is the relevant code:

```
struct cellData {
  let Title: String
  let Date: String
  let Time: String
  let Desc: String
  var Image: UIImage?
}

classTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    var arrayOfCellData = [cellData]()

   override func viewDidLoad() {

       ref = Database.database().reference()



       ref?.child("Events").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with {(snapshot) in

           let data = snapshot.value as! NSArray

            var i = 0
            while(i < data.count) {
                 let event = data[i] as! NSArray


                 if(event[0] as! String == "TRUE") {
                      self.arrayOfCellData.append(cellData(
                         Title:event[1] as! String,
                         Date:event[2] as! String,
                         Time:event[3] as! String,
                         Desc:event[4] as! String,
                         Image: nil))


                        print(self.arrayOfCellData[i])


                 }



              i += 1
            }


       })

                       print(arrayOfCellData.count)

   }

 }
```

Based on this code it should print each event individually(There are two events in the database) and **then** it should print the total amount of events in the array. However, this is what prints in the console:

```
0
cellData(Title: "Event #1", Date: "9/18/17", Time: "6:30 PM", Desc: "Generic Event Description", Image: nil)
cellData(Title: "Event #2", Date: "5/15/26", Time: "12:15 PM", Desc: "Please attend this event", Image: nil)
```

As you can see the snapshot is running after the view didLoad method. In fact, the methods defining the table views also run prior to the snapshot, causing the call to not show any of the data.

Comment: Do you know about completion handler or callbacks?

Comment: Not particularly, I understand now that the block is running asynchronously, but I'm still not sure how I can get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I just had to reload the table views from within the block. I added the line

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

and the table view would reload with the new data. The 0 was printing before the other data because the block of code that pulled the firebase data was running asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help:

I think since `observeSingleEvent` is an async call , so you need to use completion handler to give the data back:

Write a function named `fetchData` and then use it in `viewDidLoad` method:(as I mentioned in usage)

```
func fetchData(completionHandler: @escaping ([cellData]) -> Void) {
           ref = Database.database().reference()



           ref?.child("Events").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with {(snapshot) in

               let data = snapshot.value as! NSArray

                var i = 0
                while(i < data.count) {
                     let event = data[i] as! NSArray


                     if(event[0] as! String == "TRUE") {
                          self.arrayOfCellData.append(cellData(
                             Title:event[1] as! String,
                             Date:event[2] as! String,
                             Time:event[3] as! String,
                             Desc:event[4] as! String,
                             Image: nil))


                            print(self.arrayOfCellData[i])


                     }



                  i += 1
                }


                    completionHandler(self.arrayOfCellData)
               })


        }
```

Usage:

```
self.fetchData { fetchedArray in

            print(fetchedArray)
}
```